# Content Security Policy - Blocking resources even with nginx config

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, content-security-policy

It seems I am running into an issue where my app is running into CSP restrictions. For testing purposes I included into my config:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' data: blob:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob:; font-src * data: blob:; frame-src *;";
```

Here is a link to my config:

https://pastebin.com/gmVnkui2

These are the resource errors:

```
http://localhost:3000/node-api/proxy/api/v2/main-page/indexing-status   blocked connect-src _app-ea228550bb0c864c.js:1
http://localhost:3000/node-api/proxy/api/v2/stats   blocked connect-src _app-ea228550bb0c864c.js:1
http://localhost:3000/node-api/proxy/api/v2/stats/charts/transactions   blocked connect-src _app-ea228550bb0c864c.js:1
http://localhost:3000/node-api/proxy/api/v2/main-page/blocks    blocked connect-src _app-ea228550bb0c864c.js:1
http://localhost:3000/node-api/proxy/api/v2/main-page/transactions  blocked connect-src _app-ea228550bb0c864c.js:1
http://localhost:3000/node-api/proxy/api/v2/config/backend-version  blocked connect-src _app-ea228550bb0c864c.js:1
```

I apologize in advance if this is a very simple oversight on my part. I ran the following tests:

- No CSP (started this route and found the resource errors)
- Added exceptions for specific ports 3000:4000 (same resources were blocked)
- Added exceptions for every policy (same resources were blocked)
- Added unsafe-inline (same resources were blocked)

I tried adding policies to my nginx.conf as follows:

- No CSP (started this route and found the resource errors)
- Added exceptions for specific ports 3000:4000 (same resources were blocked)
- Added exceptions for every policy (same resources were blocked)
- Added unsafe-inline (same resources were blocked)

I expected the resources to remain unblocked. Even when testing in report-only mode, these resources were still blocked.

Comment: Are there other policies present in response headers or meta tag?

Comment: There is a script that runs via docker that sets CSP. However I confirmed with Blockscout that the CSPs are being set correctly server-side. So its my nginx config that seems to be the issue. I tried adding something like this for both port 4000 and port 3000

https://pastebin.com/PkP3SrBh